# Executing alternate cmds using R

Tags: r, cmd

Is it possible in R to do the following:

```
execute cmd1
if cmd1 generates error, proceed to:
execute cmd2
```

Thanks

Comment: Check out [tryCatch](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/conditions.html) in R

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`try` and/or `tryCatch` may be of use to you. Consider the super-simple toy example below:

```
#  Our function just returns it's input as long as input is not negative otherwise an error is generated
f <- function(n) {
if( n < 0 ) 
  stop("need positive integer") 
return(n)
}

# Our alternative function to run if we get an error from the first function
f2 <- function(n) return( cat( paste( "You have  a negative number which is" , n ) ) )

#  Now we try to run it with `try`:
if( class( try( f(-1) , silent = TRUE ) ) == "try-error" )
  f2(-1)
#You have  a negative number which is -1

#  And using the sophisticated `tryCatch()`  
tryCatch( f(-1) , finally = f2(-1) )
#Error in f(-1) : need positive integer
#You have  a negative number which is -1
```

The return value of `try()` is the value of the expression if it evaluates without error, otherwise an object of the `class` `"try-error"`. In the first example we just check to see if an error was generated using comparing the class of the return value of `try` and execute `f2()` if an error was generated.

Note there are quite a few ways to handle this and I certainly wouldn't advocate either of these as being the best, but they should be a useful starting point for you to learn more about error handling.

Comment: Thanks for your comments guys! I'm really appreciative. I have found this to work: fun1 <- function(n){
      n <- cmd...
      return(n)     
      cat("Method1 failed");FALSE
}

fun2 <- function(n){
      cmd...
      n <- return(n)
      cat("Method2 failed");FALSE
}

tryCatch( fun1(n), finally=fun2(n))      n is my variable name used before this cmd step and after. But I did not get any output from my cat(). Is there any way of writing error log into a file from this point? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try this, err is the error message in the try block.

```
tryCatch(stop(),
    error=function(err){
      print(1)
      print(err)
      })
```

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your use case, even simple short-circuiting of boolean operators might be enough. i.e., if your functions can return `TRUE` to indicate no-error and `FALSE` to indicate an error, then you can use the fact that `||` will only evaluate the RHS operand if the LHS operand evaluates to `FALSE`.

```
> doAwesomeStuff <- function() {cat("OMG, I'm awesome! <falls flat on face>\n"); FALSE}
> okDoNormalStuff <- function() {cat("OMG, I'm OK! :-)\n"); TRUE}
> doAwesomeStuff() || okDoNormalStuff()
OMG, I'm awesome! <falls flat on face>
OMG, I'm OK! :-)
[1] TRUE
```

But if doAwesomeStuff() works,

```
> doAwesomeStuff <- function() {cat("OMG, I'm awesome!\n"); TRUE}
> doAwesomeStuff() || okDoNormalStuff()
OMG, I'm awesome!
[1] TRUE
```